# Retrieve values from two separate sheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I send an email to a list of people. The email is generated by copying a range from one Excel sheet into the body of the email. This works fine.

All the code is below. The sheet that the body of the mail is selected from is called 'UKX Trade". I want to retrieve the email address data from a separate sheet called "Mailinfo". How can I adjust the code for this to work?

```
Sub ZC_Collar()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim StrBody As String

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
'Only the visible cells in the selection
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'You can also use a fixed range if you want
Set rng = Range("ZCCollar").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


 StrBody = Sheets("UKX Trade").Range("body_line1").Value & "<br><br>" & _
          Sheets("UKX Trade").Range("body_line2").Value & "<br>" & _
          Sheets("UKX Trade").Range("body_line3").Value


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In Columns("P").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
        LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "Q").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Index Option RFQ"
            .CC = Range("cc_email").Value           

            .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & "Thanks"

            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display  'Or use Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify where `cell` is in this line:

```
For Each cell In Columns("P").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
' ... add contacts code
Next cell
```

Do this by:

```
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Columns("P").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
' ... add contacts code
Next cell
```

This is called *fully qualifying* an object in VBA.

---

**Edit**

So here is your sub, but with things fully qualified. You'll notice that the code you got from Ron de Bruin (RangetoHTML) was already fully qualified. Put this in a **module** not a sheet.

```
Sub ZC_Collar()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim StrBody As String

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
' Remove this next line, it doesn't do anything because you set rng again anyway
' Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
' only visible cells in ZCCollar range, specifying the sheet (put the correct sheet in)
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UKX Trade").Range("ZCCollar").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UKX Trade")
    StrBody = .Range("body_line1").Value & "<br><br>" & _
              .Range("body_line2").Value & "<br>" & _
              .Range("body_line3").Value
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Columns("P").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Cells(cell.Row, "Q").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Index Option RFQ"
            .CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mailinfo").Range("cc_email").Value
            .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & "Thanks"
            .Display  'Or use Send to send each email without displaying it first
        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: *This is called fully qualifying an object in VBA* - and consistently doing it will spare you many, many, many easily avoidable run-time errors! +1

Comment: Thanks - Hi. The macro runs if I run it from sheet 'Mailinfo'. However, it does not work if I run it from sheet 'UKX Trade'. How come this is and how can I fix that please? Thanks

Comment: Store the code in a module, not in the sheet, and fully qualify your objects like I show in my answer... no reason that shouldn't work?